ms option in memoir class
Using the memoir class with the ms option I get the error "Underfull \hbox (badness 10000)" on basically every line. A minimal working example of this happening is
\documentclass[ms]{memoir}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla
\end{document}

I use MiKTeX with VS Code if that matters. I would like to use the ms option or at least the same font.

Your document compiles, correct? This is simply an informational message, not an error, so you can still use the ms option of memoir. You may also want to refer to What does the phrase "Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph" actually mean?.

welcome! ......

If you are just out for a computer modern typewriting font that works OK in text, you could try the proportial (i.e., not monospaced) one. I don't know how to use it in LaTeX, but this is how it looks.

@mickep cfr-lm provides latex support for the variable typewriter on 8-bit engines (and almost anything else you might want to use from lm). there's an updated version not yet on ctan or the older version in tl/miktex.

Don't use ms if you don't want warnings about bad boxes.
If you just want the font (why?) you can put \ttfamily at the start of your document or \renewcommand{\rmdefault}{cmtt} in your preamble.
From the manual:

ms this tries to make the document look as though it was prepared on a typewriter. Some publishers prefer to receive poor looking submissions.

So the text is not justified, inter-word spacing is rigid and pretty much every line is going to be under-full.
The only reason to use ms would be temporarily for a submission to a publisher who demanded this style. Memoir goes to a lot of trouble to produce high quality output. The ms option deliberately undoes most of that.
Typesetting your entire document in cmtt is also not a great idea, imho. There are good reasons books, newspapers, magazines etc. don't use monowidth typewriter style.
